# Memory Issues with Video Transitions in DirectShow Editing Services

Tags: directshow

I've encountered an odd, apparently memory-related issue when using DES to transition between overlapping video clips or still images, and I'm curious to know whether other DES users have found the same problem or whether it's some bug of my own that I've been unable to find.

I've found that once the timeline has a sufficient number of transitions,  the timeline will stop rendering part way through playback. No DirectShow errors occur and DirectShow doesn't report that playback has completed, but IVMRWindowlessControl9::RepaintVideo will return S_OK without drawing anything and the transform filter I've inserted in the filter chain will stop getting  its Transform() method called.

If I continue to add transitions (which also means adding new clips to transition between), playback will fail earlier and earlier in the timeline, until eventually DirectShow won't render anything at all.

Windows Task Manager indicates a steady increase in memory use during playback, with a jump each time playback reaches a transition, peaking at around a 150 mb increase in memory use at the point rendering fails. After this point, calls to new or fopen will sometimes fail, though this isn't a reliable behavior. Playing the same clips but with no transitions between them will result in about a 50mb increase in memory usage over the first three or four clips, but no further increases, and rendering never fails.

The key to how quickly failure occurs appears to be the dimensions of the input media. With 1920 x 1080 still images, failure will start to occur with around 35 transitions in the timeline; with 640 x 480 video clips, it takes around 80. Other factors - still images vs. video clips, transition length, the particular transition being used - don't seem to make a difference.

The 150 mb in extra memory will get released when I restart playback (though not when I stop it), and I can add or remove transitions during a single session to make the problem appear and disappear, which would seem to indicate against a pure memory leak, though I'm not ready to rule out anything absolutely yet.

Just in case this adds any light to the matter, my development machine is running 64-bit Windows 7.

To sum up: I'm trying to figure out whether this is a DES bug that I'm going to have to work around or whether, as often turns out to be the case, it's a bug of my own. Have other developers out there been able to create DES timelines with large numbers of transitions (50 - 100) that play successfully? Or encountered the same problem and figured out how to deal with it? Or are there any Microsoft employees lurking out there who can confirm this as a DES bug and suggest workarounds?

Thanks for taking the time to read this lengthy message,  and thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: It may be too late for an answer for the original author of this question, however I have recently run into exactly the same problem as he describes here. I tried turning Dynamic Reconnection on and it still did not resolve the issue. The problem seems to be memory related, as the behavior that is exhibited (frame gets stuck in a certain position while time continues to tick) is identical to the behavior when the system runs out of memory. I have scoured through DES documentation and discussion forums high and low and not found any answers to this issue.

Comment: It seems not many people are trying to use DES for large video projects with more than 25 transitions. Ironically, depending on the system and its capabilities/memory, I am able to reproduce this problem with around 25 images/transitions even if the images are large enough resolution and the correct transition is used (certain transitions seem to cause the problem to occur more quickly).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for an answer I think, but have you enabled dynamic reconnection with `IRenderEngine::SetDynamicReconnectLevel()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it can help, but if it is a memory related problem, try making your application LARGE ADDRESS AWARE.  We ran into a problem while re-encoding using DES for adding Overlay and when working with vidéos of resolution 1 920 × 1 200, we were always getting error like "No more memory".  For Studio 2010 setting under main project compilation, under Linker->System, put Enable Large Address to Yes and test again.  Maybe it will correct your situation.  For c# application, it is done using POST EVENT BUILDS, see this link for more informations.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/calvin_hsia/2010/09/27/out-of-memory-easy-ways-to-increase-the-memory-available-to-your-program/

Regards, Nick.

Hope it is usefull!